# Move 2000 PDFs in several folders, each containing 100 files

Tags: files, mv

I have one folder with 2000 PDF files on a Mac. Using the command line, I would like to move each 100 PDFs to another folder to be created in the same directory. So that I would have 20 folders (named 1, 2, etc.) each containing 100 PDFs in the main directory. How can I achieve that?

Comment: What are the names of the PDF files?

Comment: Something like `453041477-18100305.pdf`. The second number changes.

Comment: And how are these 100 PDFs to be chosen?  At random, by name, creation date, etc. ?

Comment: By name. Sorry, I missed that part in my original question.

Comment: So, their filename is `453041477-<n>.pdf` and you want to put them in numerical order by *n*, then move each subsequent group of 100 in a different directory?

Comment: @dr01 Yes. The folder can be created right in the same directory and named like 1, 2, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `set`, process batches of 100 files via `"${@:START:COUNT}"` (range of positional parameters) and `shift 100` while incrementing a counter `c` to create the directories:

```
set -- *.pdf
c=1
while (($#)); do
  mkdir ${c}
  if [ $# -ge 100 ]; then
    mv -- "${@:1:100}" ${c}
    c=$((c+1))
    shift 100
  else
    mv -- "${@}" ${c}
    shift $#
  fi
done
```

Comment: Thank you, don_crissti. This script did exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I have just written below bash script for your specific problem. This may help you.

```
#!/bin/bash

DEFAULT_DELIM_SIZE=100
num_of_total_file=$(ls | grep "pdf" | wc -l)
num_of_total_folder=$((num_of_total_file/DEFAULT_DELIM_SIZE))

echo "Total number of pdf files = $num_of_total_file"
echo "Total number of folder will generated if not exist $num_of_total_folder"

# create directories if not exist
for (( i = 0; i < $num_of_total_folder; i++ )); do
    if [[ ! -d $i ]]; then
        mkdir $i
    fi
done

# file name format should be like this <arbitrary_numb>-<folder_num>.pdf
for file in *.pdf; do
    prefix=$(echo $file | awk '{split($0, a, "-"); print a[2]}' | awk '{split($0, a, "."); print a[1]}')
    if [[ -d $prefix ]]; then
        mv $file $prefix
    fi
done
```

Comment: Thank you very much for posting, Talayhan. I looks good. However, it does not move any PDF to the newly created folders. The result of running your script is that it creates to me a folder 0 and folder 1 (when testing it with exactly 200 PDF), but all PDF are still in the main directory. The might be something not quite there yet with the last part of the script. Note that the correct result for the given test should be that folder 0 and folder 1 have each 100 PDF. Folder 0 the first 100, folder 1 the last 100 PDF.